# Cannot drop index column from DataFrame when convert to html

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get rid off index column, when converting DataFrame into HTML, but even though I reset index or set `index=False` in `to_html` it is still there, however with no values.

```
df = df.set_index(['ID','Name','PM', 'Theme'])['Score'].unstack()
df = df.reset_index()
df_HTML = df.to_html(table_id = "table_score", index=False, escape=False)
```

[image]

Any idea how to get rid off that, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.set_index(['ID','Name','PM', 'Theme'])['Score'].unstack()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).drop('Theme',axis=1)
df_HTML = df.to_html(table_id = "table_score", index=False, escape=False)
```

The error was caused because your theme columns seens to be your old index. And since you didnt drop in the reset_index method well, it stayed there.
If this doesnt work well just drop 'Theme'.

Comment: I tried this approach as well, but columns like "ID", 'Name' and 'PM' disappear as they are index column after unstack(), however 'Theme' remains there still :(

Comment: Check edit i think now you can do it

Comment: KeyError: "['Theme'] not found in axis"

Comment: Weird, that means the column doesnt exist in your df. So it really shouldnt appear as your image displays shows it